# Magento REST API /Product Call Returns Empty JSON Arrays

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, oauth

I'm trying to use the Magento REST API to get back a list of all products on my Magento Installation.

I've successfully authenticated using OAuth and I'm calling "*LINK TO API*/products" -- however it just returns me an array of empty arrays, like so:

```
{"11":[], "12":[], "13":[], "14":[], "15":[], "16":[], "17":[]}
```

11, 13, 13 etc are the ID's of the products in my store. So its certainly finding products, however it isn't sending any of the products details along with the IDs, which should be in the JSON arrays associated with the IDs.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and been able to fix it?

Below is the code I'm using to access the API.

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml'));
```

Thanks in Advance,

Danny

Answer (score 12):

Danny I would check the ACL for your REST USER, sounds like you haven't given it permission to the specific fields you are looking for.  Also I've noticed a bug when using the "All" will act the same as "Custom" with nothing checked.

To Get to these functions go to:

```
System > Web Services > REST - Attributes
```

1. Select the account used for the connection [recommend Admin]
2. Then verify the [ACL Attribute Rules]
3. Again use Custom and select each one you want to assure they are stored.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP. I tried this and it didn't help. I also found that in `System > Web Services > REST - Roles` you can click on a role to see another ACL... this one defining actions instead of attributes. (I guess this is handy because you can have multiple admin roles, so as well as setting the ACL for the Admin "user type" you can set different ACLs for each admin role.) But even that didn't help. I've granted the Customer role permission on all product actions & attributes but I still get the array of empty arrays.

Comment: @DougMcLean Same issue here. Did you ever find a resolution for this? If you can remember that far back...

Comment: @bredon IIRC it was just a silly caching issue - going into System > Cache Management and clicking the "Flush Magento Cache" didn't seem to work, but clicking the "Flush Cache Storage" button in the same page did the trick. At least I think it did...! Oh, one other thing: make sure you are actually accessing the API using the role you think you are. Sometimes authentication fails silently and you fall back to Guest role. A simple test in this case would be to change the attributes ACL for Guest and see if anything changes. Good luck!